# Transform string into dictionary (with additional constraints)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file where each line is a string that looks like this:

```
s='elem1 elem2 elem3 elem4 elem5'
```

I need to parse this string into a dictionary. The problem is that I want the dictionary to look like this

```
d={key1:elem1;key2:elem2;key3:elem3;key4:{elem4,elem5}}
```

The number of elements after elem3 is variable: can be only elem4 or can be elem4-elem10.

I know that I can do this with a number of nested for and while loops and a counter that adds element to a key until it reaches a number that is larger than 3, but I was thinking if there is a more pythonic way of doing it.

Also, if the file is large should I just stick to a list and place elem4-elemn into a tuple?

Comment: First read the keys and values into lists, and work from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want across both Python 2 and Python 3:

```
s = 'elem1 elem2 elem3 elem4 elem5'
v1, v2, v3, vrest = s.split(None, 3)
d = { 'key1': v1, 'key2': v2, 'key3': v3, 'key4': vrest.split() }
```

At the end, `d` will be:

```
{'key1': 'elem1', 'key3': 'elem3', 'key2': 'elem2', 'key4': ['elem4', 'elem5']}
```

(Keys are out of order because that's how `dict`s work. Note also the different syntax for the variable list associated with key4.)

In Python 3, there is a little more graceful way to do it:

```
v1, v2, v3, *vrest = s.split()
d = { 'key1': v1, 'key2': v2, 'key3': v3, 'key4': vrest }
```

This takes advantage of a "generalized unpack operation" grabbing "the rest of the values" into `vrest`. But it only works in Python 3.